# DataVisualization Extension loading error

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am following the documentation, and when I try to load the DataViz extension,

```
const ext = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DataVisualization")
```

browser gives me this error:

```
Extension not found: Autodesk.DataVisualization. Has it been registered(1)?
```

Same error comes when I try to load it via NOP_VIEWER.

Extension works when I use DataViz reference app. So, I am assuming this has to be locally loaded into my project. I searched entire Reference App project but I couldn't locate the extension code.

Could someone assist me to solve this problem.

Thank you.
Bandu

Comment: Hi Bandu, which viewer version you are using? And I believe you have followed this document: https://shrikedoc.github.io/data-visualization-doc/#/md/md/sprites-with-styles

Comment: Hi Xiaodong, I am using latest v 7.5.1 (as shown in viewer property panel). I noticed that Reference App is showing v 7.39.1. I doubt it is a public version.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang, thanks for pointing that out. I changed viewer version to 7.39 and now it works!

Comment: I forgot from which version, but yes it may not have been exposed with previous version. Glad to know it works :)

Comment: @XiaodongLiang i am using react-forge-viewer library and on top of it I am doing everything, I need to know where is that library.Is it an npm package or what?

Comment: @BanduW please see my comment

Answer (score 0):

Add in the viewer the Beta Reference:

```
<script
        src="https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/7.39.1/extensions/DataVisualization/DataVisualization.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using only extension with latest viewer doesn't work. Viewer library has to be v3.9.1. Then the extension is already there. No need to load it explicitly.